# SVG CSS keyframe animation with transform issue (<text> and <rect>)

Tags: css, animation, svg, transform

I'm Working on a (simple) loading image made in **SVG with some CSS animations**.
It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but I can't seem to make it work on Safari.

Is this a Safari (11.0.1) thing, or is there something I'm missing? A simple SVG rectangle animates fine, but text does nothing...

If someone could help it would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1400 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style>
        .oeps {
            font-family: 'SketchRockwell', 'Sketch Block', sans-serif;
            font-size: 120px;
        }
        .balk {
            -webkit-animation: vallen 1s ease-in-out infinite;
            animation: vallen 1s ease-in-out infinite;
        }
        .tekst1 {
                -webkit-animation: vallen 1s ease-in-out infinite;
                animation: vallen 1s ease-in-out infinite;
            }
        @keyframes vallen {
            0% { transform: translate(0px, 0px)}
            50% { transform: translate(20px, 0px)}
            100% { transform: translate(0px, 200px)}
        }
    </style>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1400" height="340" fill="rgb(227,6,19)"/>
    <g class="oeps" style="transform: translate(700px, 60px);">
        <text class="tekst1" x="-200" y="120" fill="white">O</text>
        <rect class="balk" x="-200" y="80" width="75" height="4" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#494949"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the prefixed version of the animation CSS property: `-webkit-animation`.  When you do that, you also need to use the prefixed version of `@keyframes`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes vallen {
   ..etc..
}
```

Now I'm not sure whether the Safari version you are using supports the unprefixed version of these properties or not, but try it. Perhaps that's your problem.

Comment: The Safari i'm using doesn't need the prefixes. Deleted them and [posted it on Codepen](https://codepen.io/boasthin/pen/Bmezmv) The weird thing is that a rectangle does animate, but the text element doesn't move.